# C program not printing values

Tags: c, double, degrees

I am writing a program that converts decimal degrees to degrees, minutes, seconds.
This is what it is supposed to do:

```
-118.1406209154 = 118 degrees 8 minutes 26.2342 seconds West.
W     If it is negative then it is either west longitude or south latitude
118     The degrees are left of the decimal place
8     Multiply the decimal portion (0.140620915) by 60 to get decimal minutes (8.4372549). The minutes are left of the decimal place.
26.2353     Multiply the decimal portion (0.4372549) by 60 to get decimal seconds.
```

This is the code I have so far, however, the problem when I run it is it only prints the decimalDegrees value and nothing else. I cannot figure out why. Any tip/help is much appreciated.

```
double decimalDegrees = -118.1406209154;

double degrees;
double minutes;
double seconds;
char longitude;
char latitude;
double temp;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    minutes = decimalDegrees - (int)decimalDegrees; //get the decimal portion of decimalDegrees
    degrees = decimalDegrees - minutes; //get degrees by removing the decimal portion
    minutes = minutes*60.0;
    temp = minutes - (int)minutes; //get decimal portion
    minutes = minutes - temp; //remove decimal portion from minutes
    seconds = temp * 60.0;

    printf("%0.10lf ", decimalDegrees);
    printf("%lf degrees ", degrees);
    printf("%lf minutes ", minutes);
    printf("%0.4lf seconds ", seconds);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It prints `-118.1406209154 -118.000000 degrees -8.000000 minutes -26.2353 seconds ` in my machine

Comment: I see. This is very weird.

Comment: Put an `\n` at the end of your last `printf()` string, and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: no, still only printing the decimalDegree

Comment: What compiler/platform are you using? Change your `%lf` to `%f` in your `printf()` format strings, too.

Comment: I am using CodeLite with MinGW compiler.
I changed the \n as well as the %f but still not working

Comment: Show what include files code is using.

Comment: BTW: 1) there is an additional problem with this approach.  Try `decimalDegrees = 0.0166666597` --> `0.000000 degrees 0.000000 minutes 60.0000 seconds`  2) Better to use `floor()` of other FP functions than `(int)` as `(int)` has such a limited range.

Comment: You need `#include <stdio.h>`. Update your code to have the changes suggested by Paul as well as this include, and check it still gives the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me fine, so far. Perhaps you should attempt this with a different compiler, if you are using a unix based system, you could try using GCC if you haven't already, or Xcode if you are using a Mac, and if running windows MinGW has been a popular choice (a GCC solution for windows).

Taking into account what others have already said, you could better your code a little while you are at it. As Paul suggested, the use of `%lf` is unnecessary to use in printf here, but if you intend for the user to enter their own values in later on, you will use `%lf` for reading in doubles using `scanf()`.